# Wrong 16 bytes in decryption using AES

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, byte, aes

I am using AES to decrypt the ciphertext. I am getting initial 16 bytes wrong in all cases. I am using C++. I don't know what's wrong with the code. I am getting 16 bytes wrong then partial decrypted message is there. I have done many solutions present on SO but not working anyone. Please help what the problem can be. Thanks.

Please find my code below:

```
bytearray *DecryptResponse::decrypt(bytearray cleartext, bytearray iv,
        bytearray hmac) {


bytearray encryptionKey = mykeyBundle[0];

String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
String KEY_ALGORITHM_SPEC = "AES";
bytearray* outputMessage;
try {
    Cipher* cipher = Cipher::getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec secKey = *(new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey,
            KEY_ALGORITHM_SPEC));
    IvParameterSpec _iv = *(new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    cipher->init(Cipher::DECRYPT_MODE, secKey, _iv);
    outputMessage = cipher->doFinal(cleartext);
} catch (Exception &e) {
    cout << "Exception getCause" << e.getCause() << endl;
    cout << "Exception getMessage" << e.getMessage() << endl;
    cout << "Check for the Encryption Key. It might be wrong input!"
            << endl;
}

cout<<"sizes: "<< cleartext.size()<<" "<<((*(outputMessage)).size());
return outputMessage;
```

Now, Output is this:

```
\��6����_)�stdllections":{},"default":["fT1ICn+rqet0S8/AAXDiuto7FTRqIi3SzA=","oQq7EokSPqAoGHgj974G0tFsw6c="],"collection":"crypto"}
```

Comment: How you generate IV ? You need to use same IV as the one who encrypted the text.

Comment: @kulatamicuda I have ciphertext, IV, hmac with me when I got message from server. Then, I decrypted it using the library API using AES. I am not generating IV. It is coming from server side. And, I am using that IV only to decrypt my data.

Comment: @hellodear And that IV is not repeated at the start of the ciphertext as well?

Comment: @owlstead No. I don't know about this. You can tell if how to check that. I will see that. Tell me what would happen in both the cases: when it is repeated and when it's not.

Comment: Well, check if the first 16 bytes are identical to the bytes of the IV. What is more to tell?

Comment: If I look at the 16 initial characters of ciphertext & IV in the response, then they are not equal. I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: The IV is still the most likely culprit - maybe it is converted wrong, or maybe it is just plain wrong. We don't have enough information to solve your question otherwise. Can you show us code & sample input/output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64940/discussion-between-hellodear-and-owlstead).

Comment: @owlstead I have edited the question with what you said. Please check it once.

Comment: Please try and add a (sample) key and IV in hex, as well as the first 16 bytes of plaintext in hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the first 16 bytes of ciphertext are : XOR of actual plaintext and IV key. I just need to XOR it with IV after decryption. That's the solution. Thanks @owlstead for your valuable input.